# docker installation on Windows

Tags: windows, docker, docker-machine

I have installed Docker in my windows 10 machine.

When i open power-shell and check docker version it shows below

```
PS C:\Users\XXXXX> docker --version
Docker version 19.03.4, build 9013bf5
```

But when i ran Docker images or docker run it did not worked

```
PS C:\Users\XXXXX> docker images
error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.40/images/json: open 
//./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the 
default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This 
error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
```

For Docker run

```
PS C:\Users\XXXX> docker run hello-world
docker : C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: error during connect: Post 
http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.40/containers/create: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The 
system cannot find 
the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run 
 elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
```

I am not getting if docker is installed then why docker images and docker run are not working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the **Docker service** is runnig.

(1) Go to **Services**.

(2) Check service **Docker for Windows** is running.

You can **stop/start** the service as well using below commands in command prompt.

```
Net stop com.docker.service

Net start com.docker.service
```

Refer article : https://success.docker.com/article/docker-for-windows-fails-with-a-daemon-not-running-message

Comment: I asked my Admin guy to run the above start command but still getting below error ...........................                                                                                            
        error during connect:      Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.40/images/json: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.

Comment: Please check Event Viewer if there is any log for this issue.

Comment: I could not find anything in Event Log.But when i check services i can see Docker app is running.

Answer (score 0):

Have you manually started docker after the installation?

[Install Docker Desktop on Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/)

Comment: I folled this doc.But when i click on Docker Desktop it neither appears in task-bar nor in notification area.

Comment: can you test with running cmd/powershell as admin?